# What Impact Does Meat Curing/Preservation Have on Nutritional Content?

Tags: food-preservation, nutrient-composition, food-processing

I am currently trying to research nutritional facts for cured meats and other preserved foods.  In specific, I am looking for any information about the caloric impact that preservation methods might have.  For example, is 100g portion of chicken drumsticks the same amount of calories as, say, a 100g that is then smoked, cured, or, goodness forbid, pickled [I truly hope this is not really a thing, but...pickled pigs feet exist, so who can say].

From my research on the USDA pages, I cannot find anything specific that hints at or discusses any changes.  The closest related thing I was able to find was a basic justification from the meat industry for why processed meats are not as bad as some consumers fear.  While it touches on the various methods of preservation, it does not go into any real details on the impacts to nutritional content, excepting for sodium levels being discussed.

Any details that can be shared are greatly appreciated.  I am working on a somewhat realistic, but also simplistic (only calories truly matter) food system for a programming task, and would like to insert enough reality for the various things commonly done to food to matter as they would in our everyday lives.

Comment: Think about a juicy apple, now dehydrate it in slices to make it last longer. As the water goes away, the caloric energy rises per mass of apple.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks to your comment, I realized that I made a poor choice in wording my question initally.  What i meant by the question is to say a 100g portion of plain drumstick, vs the same 100g portion after it is processed into a cured, smoked, pickled, or otherwise preserved final product.

My apologies for that; you are right if it was strictly 100g of plain vs processed, in some, the density would change to go higher or lower.